# File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-datetimepicker using tailwind framework in ruby on rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bootstrap-datetimepicker, eonasdan-datetimepicker, tailwind-css

I am using bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails rails gem for datetimepicker in my rails project. I integrated my project to use tailwind css and now I am facing  "File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-datetimepicker" error while trying to run the application. 
Steps followed:

```
Gem file:
gem 'momentjs-rails', '>= 2.9.0'
gem 'bootstrap3-datetimepicker-rails', '~> 4.17.47'

application.js

//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker

application.scss

@import 'bootstrap-datetimepicker';

Error :

index.js:24 Uncaught Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):

@import "bootstrap-datetimepicker";
^
      File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-datetimepicker.
      in C:\Users\ES0074223\RubyOnRails\firefly\app\javascript\stylesheets\application.scss (line 41, column 1)
    at Object../node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js?!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (index.js:24)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Object../app/javascript/stylesheets/application.scss (application.scss:2)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at Module../app/javascript/packs/application.js (application.js:6)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:19)
    at bootstrap:83
    at bootstrap:83
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to load your assets through the asset pipeline and with sprocket comments syntax, but while using webpack, even though this is possible, the easiest way would be to install your dependencies directly with yarn.

Add it like:

```
yarn add bootstrap-datetimepicker
yarn add bootstrap
```

For this to work you will also have to set `less-loader` as bootstrap-datetimepicker uses less files and add bootstrap separatly.

After setting the loader you can require them with something like:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~bootstrap-datetimepicker/src/less/bootstrap-datetimepicker
```

Otherwise just use Flatpickr which is easier to manage and install.